# escape if array is empty to avoid error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
for(var i=0;i < obj.length; i++){
obj[i].split(",");
}
```

above code gave me split of undefined, it's because my last item of obj is an array that look like this

```
[""]
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What else does the array contain? Numbers, or only strings/undefined? Can it contain `null` values?

Comment: Can you give us a sample array of obj? As you said, the last item was an array. But in that case it should return .split is not a function not split of undefined

Comment: You don't have to iterate over the entire length...Also your loop body won't mutate the strings within your object.

Comment: Make everything to be String, `obj[i].toString().split(",")` should fix this.

Comment: Good Question! Though when I tried same over fiddle, it was returning empty string to me rather than split on undefined. This could be a version issue though. See my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Iterate through items if and only it is of type *string* and `obj[i]` is [*true value*](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

```js
var obj = ['', null, 100, undefined, 'abc,test'];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  if (typeof obj[i] === 'string' && obj[i]) {
    var test = obj[i].split(",");
    console.log(test);
  }
}
```

**[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/77huev0x/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are referring to an empty string rather than undefined, please correct me if I'm wrong on that.  If it is the "undefined" value which is different than an empty string, providing what your list is would be helpful.  If it's really an empty string, just use an if condition to skip it.

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i] != '') { 
        obj[i].split(','); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Empty string is not `undefined` I suppose!

Comment: Hmm...  I'm actually assuming she means an empty string given her output, when I do a quick test, I get the same output, but I could be wrong.  I'll write that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your array doesn't contain numbers (like zero) or boolean values (like `true`), then you can do this:

```
for( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ ) {
  ( obj[i] || "" ).split(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all , what you are doing has no purpose with your code.

Namely ;

```
var obj = { a : "there,are,commas", b : "no commas" } ; 
// next line of code doesnt do anything, 
//just returns undefined on console.
obj["a"].split(",");
```

Bunch of undefined s are because of this fact. 
On console, of course.

```
// if you want to use it, you might have assigned it to a variable
var someVariable = obj["a"].split(",");
```

So your problem might be something different.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling toString on your array or more prominently make everything string by using toString method on obj[i].

```
var obj = ["23",[""]]
for(var i=0;i < obj.length; i++){
  if(!obj[i].toString()==""){
   console.info(obj[i].split(","));
  }
}
```

Fiddle below for practical.

https://jsfiddle.net/stm0qemn/1/